# Extjs : Selecting same value in multiselect combo not removing value

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs5

I am using ext5 multiselect combo. If we select a value from the dropdown, say 'Other' and click outside to cancel the dropdown. 
Now the value 'Other' will be shown in combo.
Again click the dropdown and select tha same value 'Other', it should remove 'Other' from its values. But rather it adds same value once again.

[image: Here is the image:]
My code is given below:

```
        xtype: 'combo',
        emptyText: 'Retail BI',
        name: 'chainRefId',
        store: Ext.create('shared.store.filter.ChainRefs'),
        displayField: 'name',
        multiSelect: true,
        valueField: 'chain_ref_id',
        listeners: {
            expand: function(){                 
                this.getStore().load();    
            },
            change: function(combo, newVal) {
                if (!combo.eventsSuspended) {
                    var storeCombo = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('combo[name=storeId]')[0];
                    storeCombo.getStore().removeAll();
                    storeCombo.setValue(null);
                    var chainCombo = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('combo[name=chainId]')[0];
                    chainCombo.getStore().removeAll();
                    chainCombo.setValue(null);                          
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there a solution for this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you expect it to remove a value on its second select? Is that your specific requirement?

Comment: Yes. It is the requirement. And it is the default functionality of multicombo. There is no issue for the similar multicombos with the same code.
In the dropdown, if the value is already select, it should be hightlighted (like that blue one shown in image). But in my case the value selected first is not being highlighted when clicking the dropdown the second time.

Comment: Using `multiselect: true` on combos is [deprecated](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-multiSelect) since 5.1. Consider using [Multiselector](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.view.MultiSelector) or [Tag Field](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Tag) instead.

Comment: Thank you Drake, Let me try that.

Comment: The problem is I cannot change this single combo to multiselector/tagfiled.
Similar combos are used widely around the application. And I have issue on only this one.

Answer (score 0):

Your combo's store gets reloaded on each expand. Technically the record corresponding to the value you selected the first time disappears on the second store load, so the removing logic does not "see" it and therefore leaves it in the field.

Remove this:

```
expand: function(){                 
    this.getStore().load();    
}
```

and just use `autoLoad: true` on the store.

Comment: It is required for me to load on each expand, since its value changes corresponding to the values of other combos. I am passing values of  other fields as params on each expand.
So expand function cannot be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. I have provided a workaround for this. This fix holds good for tagfield too.

```
//on combo store load event
load: function () {
    // I am assuming reference to combo
    var rawVal = combo.getValue(); 
    // If combo is multiselct, getValue returns an array of selected items.
    // When combo is configured as remote, everytime it loads with new records and therefore removes the old reference.
    // Hence, do setValue to set the value again based on old reference.
    combo.setValue(rawVal);
    // Here you can see, based on old reference of selected items, the drop down will be highlighted.
}
```